# Berkeley DB: DbEnv::lsn_reset takes a very long time

Tags: c++, database, berkeley-db

I'm using Berkeley DB with a probably relatively large database file (2.1 GiB, using btree format in case it matters).  During application shutdown, DbEnv::lsn_reset is called in order to "flush" everything before exiting the application.  For the large database, this routine takes a very long time for me -- 10 minutes or so at least, during which heavy disk access happens.

Is this normal or the result of using Berkeley DB in some wrong way?  Is there anything that can be done to make things process faster?  In particular, which parameters could be tweaked to improve performance here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DbEnv::lsn_reset() is probably not what you want.  That function rewrites every single page in the database, so that you can close the databases out and open them in a different environment.  It's going to write out at least 2.1 GiB, and pretty slowly.

If you're just shutting the application down to be started back up sometime later, you may simply just want to do a DbEnv::txn_checkpoint() to flush the database log and insert a checkpoint record.  Though, this isn't required either.  As long as you have the logs committed to stable storage, you can simply exit your application.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17276_01/html/api_reference/CXX/txncheckpoint.html

Comment: Thanks!  I actually didn't write the code in question, I'm just trying to improve the existing application's performance.  I think the requirement is that no logs need to be kept in addition to the database file after shutting down.  Do I understand it correctly that txn_checkpoint already fully removes the need to keep the logs?  And what exactly does "open in a different environment" mean?  Can't the files be opened by BDB after copying to another machine, for instance, without using lsn_reset?  If that's the case, why not?

Comment: I'd take a look here to see if you need the "hotbackup" feature, or you can just deal with a regular backup: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17275_01/html/programmer_reference/transapp_archival.html .   I think you'll run into troubles in practice if you simply checkpoint, then ditch the logs.  You'll certainly be able to recover the database manually, but it may not open up in your application without some trouble.

Comment: As for lsn_reset: your entire database is marked as being owned by a certain environment and its logs.  The lsn_reset call totally breaks that dependency, so you don't need the logs any more, and you can open the database in another application entirely.  If that's what you need, then that's what you need... you unfortunately have to re-write the whole database though. :(

Comment: Thanks!  Can this be summarised to the conclusion, that I should keep all log files since the last lsn_reset, and that I need lsn_reset either to get rid of the log files or to move the database files to a different machine?

Comment: Exactly right!  Hold onto those log files until you run lsn_reset.